# Automatically call function on column upon select or insert

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, postgis, wkb

I'm trying to find a way to automatically call a function on a specific column, without actually calling it in the sql statement.

I'm using PostGIS with types for different kinds of geometry. I need to insert and select said geometric columns in the Well-Known Binary (WKB) format, which requires calling `ST_GeomFromWKB()` for inserting WKB, and `ST_AsBinary()` to retrieve data in the same format.

Suppose I have a table as defined:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS geomtest (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    geom geometry(POLYGON, 4326) NOT NULL
);
```

I would like to define a way to call the appropriate functions on the `geom` column, while referencing the column on its own, for instance, if I were to call:

```
SELECT * FROM geomtest;
```

Behind the scenes, I would like to call:

```
SELECT id, name, ST_AsBinary(geom) FROM geomtest;
```

Same thing for inserts, but instead calling `ST_GeomFromWKB()` behind the scenes.

Note that the type returned by default is `geometry` (in hex format) but after calling ST_AsBinary(), the type is `bytea`.

I've tried to use views to get this to work. It worked for selecting, but not inserting. I've also looked into Rules and Triggers, but I'm not sure if it's possible to do what I'm hoping for.

Is there an sql solution to this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Your example select statement really doesn't say much. When you say "while referencing the column on its own", do you mean "for a given geom value, perform some other statement with that geom value?"

Comment: @J Spratt So for example, if I were to call `SELECT id, name, geom FROM geomtest;`, I would really want it to do `SELECT id, name, ST_AsBinary(geom)` behind the scenes. Same with insert, but calling `ST_GeomFromWKB()`. Is this possible, since the types will be different?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do your "automatic" SELECT abstraction. You could try a lateral join but you'd still be typing it. I'll give an example in an answer. You can perform the transformation on INSERT with a trigger. I'm not too familiar with PostGIS but I gave it my best attempt.

Comment: It should work with a view and an [`INSTEAD OF`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-createtrigger.html) trigger on insert/update (and delete...)

Comment: @JGH That is the correct answer.